# Are factors such as Intellisense support and strong typing enough to justify the use of an 'Anaemic Domain Model'?

Tags: domain-driven-design, domain-model, model, object-oriented

It's easy to accept that objects should be used in all layers except a layer nominated as a data layer. However, it's just as easy to end-up with an 'anaemic domain model' that is just an object representation of data with no real functionality ( http://martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html ).

However, using objects in this fashion brings the benefit of factors such as Intellisense support, strong typing, readability, discoverability, etc.

Are these factors strong arguments for an otherwise, anaemic domain model?

Comment: I don't see how you would not get exactly the same benefits with a proper domain model.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends, surely, of what are your options.

You should understand that alternative to "(anemic) domain model" is not "something without strong-typing", but "data transfer objects". Both are strong-typed (with all included benefits), but there's strong semantic difference between them.

Comment: Good point, thanks. I agree that the difference between the two is only semantic. However, it may be significant in conveying the model's purpose.

Comment: @DavidOsborne of course it is. What Fowler warns of, I think, is "Domain Model" that still thinks and calls itself domain, but is, in fact, simple DTO. There're two major options we can choose from: DTO's and logic in service, and Domain Model and logic in it. In my opinion, the worst case is mix between these two options, when no one knowns where to put logic and where to look for one.

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from the article:

The programming language does not matter. So

> factors such as Intellisense support, strong typing, readability, discoverability, etc.

do not matter to the authors opinion.

One problem I see is to distinct between your **domain** and your **use-cases**.

For me the domain belongs into the domain model and the use-cases into the services. But I have not much experience with large-software-developement.